# How to display a uneditable checkbox instead of the word "True" in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I create a column in a table in MVC4 to show an uneditable checkbox instead of the word true.

```
@foreach (var m in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@m.UserLogin
        </td>
        <td>@m.UserEmployeeName
        </td>
        <td>@m.UserAccessRightsID
        </td>
        <td>@m.SystemManager @*CHECK BOX SHOULD BE HERE*@
        </td>
```

Here is a screen shot of what I am currently getting.
[image: Table screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked='@m.SystemManager' disabled="disabled" />
```

It uses the Razor V2 feature which removes the attribute if the value is null or false.

[You can read more about it here](http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/10/whats-new-in-razor-v2.html/)

Comment: being really picky how would I get it centered in the <td>? I have tried text-align:center but no luck